# How to make upstart execute a daemon application at startup (linux)

Tags: daemon, startup, init, spawn, upstart

In my Linux mint(Olivia) system, I put an executable shell script in my home directory 
Inside that shell script (daemonize_me.sh) there is a command that invokes daemonize application,
the daemonize application task is to execute as a daemon an application that is passed to it as argument.

Inside the daemonize.sh is as follows

```
#!/bin/bash
REG_WRK_DIR="/home/sina/`Desktop`/CollectedDaemons/regulator_workdir/"
REG_LOG_DIR=$REG_WRK_DIR"log/"
REG_EXEC_FILE=$REG_WRK_DIR"QtProjectWork"
REG_STDERR_LOG_FILE=$REG_WRK_DIR"log/error.log"
REG_STDOUT_LOG_FILE=$REG_WRK_DIR"log/output.log"
REG_PID_FILE=$REG_WRK_DIR"reg_daemon.pid"
REG_LOCK_FILE=$REG_WRK_DIR"lock_pid.lock"

myExec="daemonize -a -c "${REG_WRK_DIR}" -e "${REG_STDERR_LOG_FILE}" -o "${REG_STDOUT_LOG_FILE}" -p "${REG_PID_FILE}" -l "${REG_LOCK_FILE}" "${REG_EXEC_FILE}
echo $myExec
eval $myExec
result=$?
if [ $result -eq 0 ];then
    result=`echo -e "Daemon started at :">>${REG_STDERR_LOG_FILE};date >> ${REG_STDERR_LOG_FILE}`
        echo -e "Daemon has started"
        echo -e $result
else
        echo -e "Daemon did not start (may be it has already started!)"
        echo -e $result
fi
```

This bash script works fine in terminal when I run it as a user, after running it returns to shell prompt and I can see in top/htop that the process is still running in memory even I close terminal or .... (so no hangup signal ,.... does kill the process) 
While I will get ouput,error logfiles ,lock, and PID number after the daemonizer starts.

The challenge is, I have to run this script (daemonize_me.sh) when the system boots.
So I tried to use upstart ( which is already installed) to execute the daemonizeme.sh

I add following configuration (regulator.conf) file with following contents:

```
respawn
script      
    export HOME="/home/sina/Desktop/CollectedDaemons/regulator_workdir"
    echo -e "Going to start regulating Daemon" > /home/sina/Desktop/CollectedDaemons/regulator_workdir/log/upstart.info
    exec sudo -u /home/sina/Desktop/CollectedDaemons/daemonize_me.sh
end script
```

After saving the config file in /etc/init/regulator.conf and fixing the file privileges to 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 685 jan  8 14:35 regulator.conf

Nothing starts! I have no created file by echo,no daemon , ... nothing at all ?

In fact the deamonize_me.sh and its directory and sub-directories all have 0755 privileges.
So what is wrong, I have to use monit to monitor my daemon and if upstart does not work properly I have to add it to init.d that I do not know how.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`start on`](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/wiki/Stanzas#start_on) stanza in your Upstart script if you want to start your daemon on boot. To start it manually try something like `service regulator start`.